# page speed font link google fonts

Tags: css, caching, testing, browser

I have made an application in Symfony2 and passed the test as GTmetrix or pigdom and return this error:

The Following resources are missing a cache validator. Resources que no not specify a cache validator can not be refreshed efficiently. Specify a Last-Modified or ETag header to enable cache validation for the Following resources:

http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quintessential

Anyone know how I could remove this error? a greeting.

---

thanks for your answer:
my htaccess file is :

```
Options +indexes

Header unset ETag
FileETag None
<FilesMatch "(?i)^.*\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
Header unset Last-Modified
Header set Expires "Fri, 6 Jan 2013 00:00:00 GMT"

ExpiresActive On     
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

Header set Cache-Control "public, no-transform"
</FilesMatch>

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css application/javascript
```

sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

have you tried testing with YSlow?

You might be having problems with Expire.

Have you modified your .htaccess file?

This might help: 
[Leverage browser caching](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching#LeverageBrowserCaching)